# HttpClient GetAsync with a hash in URL

Tags: c#, http, url, .net-core

.NET Core 2.2 console application on Windows.

I'm exploring how to use HttpClient GetAsync on a Stackoverflow share style URL eg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29809054/26086  which returns a 302 redirect URL with a hash in it

```
static async Task Main()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    // 1. Doesn't work - has a hash in URL
    var url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808915/why-use-async-await-all-the-way-down/29809054#29809054";
    HttpResponseMessage rm = await client.GetAsync(url);
    Console.WriteLine($"Status code: {(int)rm.StatusCode}"); // 400 Bad Request

    // 2. Does work - no hash
    url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808915/why-use-async-await-all-the-way-down/29809054";
    rm = await client.GetAsync(url);
    Console.WriteLine($"Status code: {(int)rm.StatusCode}"); // 200 Okay

    // 3. Doesn't work as the 302 redirect goes to the first URL above with a hash
    url = "https://stackoverflow.com/a/29809054/26086";
    rm = await client.GetAsync(url);
    Console.WriteLine($"Status code: {(int)rm.StatusCode}"); // 400 Bad Request
}
```

I'm crawling my blog which has many SO short codes in it.

**Update/Workaround**
With thanks to @rohancragg I found that turning off AutoRedirect then getting the URI from the returned header worked

```
// as some autoredirects fail due to #fragments in url, handle redirects manually
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { AllowAutoRedirect = false };
var client = new HttpClient(handler);

var url = "https://stackoverflow.com/a/29809054/26086";    
HttpResponseMessage rm = await client.GetAsync(url);

// gives the desired new URL which can then GetAsync
Uri u = rm.Headers.Location;
```

Comment: URLs sent to servers don't contain the `#` fragment. It's only of use in a client such as e.g. a browser.

Comment: That makes sense thank you. I'm digging into why it is giving a 400 now as I would like for HttpClient to ignore the hash. I've updated the question to highlight the reason I need to do this ie a StackOverflow share url.

Comment: As @Damien_The_Unbeliever implies, you'll just need to strip off the hash and everything after it - all that does is tell the browser to jump to that anchor tag in the HTML page (see: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_anchor_hash.asp). So this would mean that your option 2 is your only option in this case...

Comment: You could also use the Uri class to parse the Uri and ignore any 'fragments': https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.fragment

Comment: Thanks @rohancragg - but what if I'm requesting https://stackoverflow.com/a/29809054/26086 which then returns the 302, and automatically requests the URL with a hash in it. Maybe I'll have to stop the autoredirect https://stackoverflow.com/a/10647245/26086 and then strip off the hash, then do another request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Damien_The_Unbeliever implies in a comment, you'll just need to strip off the hash and everything after it - all that does is tell the browser to jump to that anchor tag in the HTML page (see: https://w3schools.com/jsref/prop_anchor_hash.asp).

You could also use the Uri class to parse the Uri and ignore any 'fragments': https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.fragment

Because the share-style Urls are only ever going to return a 302 then I'd suggest capturing the Uri to which the 302 is referring and do as I suggest above and just get the path and ignore the fragment.

So you need to use some mechanism (which I'm just looking up!) to handle a 302 gracefully followed by option 2

**Update:** this looks relevant! [How can I get System.Net.Http.HttpClient to not follow 302 redirects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453892/how-can-i-get-system-net-http-httpclient-to-not-follow-302-redirects)

**Update 2**  Steve Guidi has a very important bit of advice in  a comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17758758/5351

In response to the advice that you need to use `HttpResponseMessage.RequestMessage.RequestUri`:

> it is very important to add `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`
>   as the second parameter of the `GetAsync()` call

---

***Disclaimer*** - I've not tried the above, this is just based on reading ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to encode your URL before send the request using HttpUtility class, this way any special character will be escaped.

```
using System.Web;

var url = $"htpps://myurl.com/{HttpUtility.UrlEncode("#1234567")}";
```

Comment: Thank you Vinick - I think I need another tactic to bend HttpClient into what I want it to do ie respond correctly when I give a url such as: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29809054/26086